# Keep running CountdownTimer in Background without services

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments, countdowntimer

i an developing a simple task in which i want to make a countdown timer running still in background when my app is stopped and closed. and all this work should b done without using android services...
Here is the code what i am using. in this code time keeps running in background when i Minimizes my app not close... but when i close my app then it starts from beginning which is not suitable for me... what i want that the time keeps on running until i close my app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 90000;
private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
private Button mButtonStartPause;
private Button mButtonReset;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private boolean mTimerRunning;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
private long mEndTime;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
    mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
    startTimer();


}

private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(START_TIME_IN_MILLIS, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
}
  private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (START_TIME_IN_MILLIS / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (START_TIME_IN_MILLIS / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();

        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", mEndTime);
        START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        Comm.endTime = (int) START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        startTimer();



}
```

}

Comment: According to me, it is not possible without using service after killing app.

Comment: Then any solution or suggestion that what should i do for this...

Comment: if you dont want to use service than save the time on app close in shared preference and start it, from that point when app restart from previous time

Comment: ok i got the point.. .thanks man... you saved my life...